# Why do I need to apply modifiers for rendering to work in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm using the new blender 3.0 version and I noticed when  go into cycles it renders as if the modifiers are not on.

[image: Example render showing modifiers not being on.]

I looked this up and can't find a single thing about this. this file is from blender 2.9 by the way. The only way that fixed it is when I applied the modifiers.

the file: [image]

Comment: I can only guess that both of the above images are from Cycles renders in the 3d-View?  One without modifiers applied (left) and one with them applied (right)?  This is a rather terse question.   You might also need to include your Cycles settings, or to be brief include your file (via https://blend-exchange.com/ ), perhaps with some of each mesh missing if you consider it proprietary.  Then someone might be motivated to investigate further.

Comment: the left is viewport shading, the right is cycles viewport. in blender 2.9, it would appear and render in cycles exactly as it had it, smooth and with modifiers and all. when i turn on and off my modifiers with the realtime display option on modifiers, i can see in the cycles viewport that it's showing the smooth geometry with the orange outline but it still appears as if it doesnt have the modifier on it, almost like the unmodified geometry is overtop the modified one. it renders as if unmodified too. here is the file https://file.io/VrwIXPjHjkYR

Comment: Please don't use external sites to post your blender file. In this case it would be deleted after the first download so isn't available now. Please use the Blend-Exchange [upload page](https://blend-exchange.com/help) or https://pasteall.org/blend/ and paste the link to it into your question.

Comment: oh im sorry! i had no clue these sites existed, i had a hard time finding a place to upload files without needing to send to someone's email.

Comment: The file you've uploaded renders fine both in 2.93 and 3.0 here although you have a few problems with overlapping vertices and inverted normals in the middle of the glasses. The mirror is already applied on those, but I suspect the modifier didn't have clipping turned on on when you modelled those. - The ugly line in the middle is because you have overlapping vertices and internal faces and the normals are inverted on one side. There's no overall distortion on the render though so I'm not sure what's causing your problem to be honest.

Comment: It's odd, the file you uploaded doesn't have the problem stated on your post.

Comment: i don't know, no matter what file i open, it has this issue where the modifiers won't show nor render if they aren't applied. is there some setting i'm missing in the render tab?

Comment: The only modifiers I can see in the file you uploaded are a few mirrors and Subsurf on most objects.

Comment: I've just noticed that you're using Blender version 3.1 alpha which is an experimental version and will probably change almost daily. Do you still get the problem if you use the [3.0 release version](https://www.blender.org/download/)?